# "_func" not being imported even when declared in __all__

Tags: python, module, python-import, python-2.x, pep8

I am using Python 2.

I was able to find that `__all__` by default does not pass `_functions` (underscored "internal" functions) when `__all__` is *not* declared (i.e. just using `from module import *` but without `__all__` explicitly defined).  However, I'm also seeing that `_functions` are not passed even if they are added to `__all__`.

What words am I missing in my question to find the answer to this?  Is this a continued "issue" (or expected behavior?) in Python 3?

My example is:

I have a mix of internal and external functions I am creating.  Currently my bypass for this issue was to put the `_functions` (underscored functions, aka "internal functions", *renamed without the underscore*) into a `._internal_module_folder` and then import the `._internal_module_folder` into a `external_module` and add the external functions to the `__all__` of `external_module` but leave out the internal functions.

So my original tree (with the issue) would look something like this:

```
/
    modules_folder/
        _internal_module_folder/
            __init__.py
            _internal_module.py
        __init__.py
        external_module.py
```

where:

`modules_folder/_internal_module_folder/__init__.py`:

```
from ._internal_module import *
```

`modules_folder/_internal_module_folder/internal_module.py`:

```
__all__ = [
    # functions:
    'ext_func1',
    'ext_func2',

    # _functions:
    '_intl_func1', 
    '_intl_func2']

def ext_func1(*args, **kwargs):
    pass
def _int_func1(*args, **kwargs):
    pass
# etc.
```

`modules_folder/__init__.py`:

```
from external_module import * # Should import _functions from __all__??
```

`modules_folder/external_module.py`:

```
from ._internal_module_folder import *
__all__ = ['ext_func1', 'ext_func2'] + list_of_external_functions_from_this_module
<define external_functions_from_this_module some of which use _int_func1>
```

When run I get an error that `_int_func1` does not exist even though it's in `__all__` explicitly?

My solution:

I renamed `_int_func` to `int_func`, changed the import in `modules_folder/__init__.py` to `from . import _internal_module as im` and then aliased the internal functions on call (for ease of *Find Definition* in VS Code and change the function to NOT be called with the default `__all__`) with `_int_func1 = im.int_func1`.

Is this PEP 8 approved?

Summary: Put `_function` into `__all__` but it wasn't passed on `from module import *`.

Comment: I can't see `_function` anywhere in your example code.

Comment: "I'm also seeing that `_functions` are not passed even if they are added to `__all__`" - where/how do you see that?

Comment: Apologies I wrote my bypass, not the problem.  The bypass as described was:
Currently my bypass for this issue was to put the `_functions` (renamed without the underscore) into a `._internal_module_folder`....

I've updated the post to show the PROBLEM code.